# Shared memory in Rust

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, automatic-ref-counting, rwlock

Environment:

macOS Sonoma Ver.14.0 (M1 mac)
Rust Ver.1.65.0

What I want to do:
I want to share a vec with an array of [u8;128] elements between multithreads.
The requirements I want to perform when sharing are as follows.

1. the entire vec must be readable
2. to be able to rewrite elements of a specific [u8; 128] type in the vec
3. be able to insert data of type [u8; 128] into vec

Below is the code I wrote, but this code can do up to reading, but there is a problem that the writing is not reflected.
If I run this code and then run the following command once on the computer where it was executed

```
    nc -v localhost 50051
```

```
    [[0u8; 128],[1u8; 128],[2u8; 128]]
```

will be output.
This is correct up to this point, but the data output on the second run is the same as the first run.
My intention is that the second element will output data with 3 fillings as shown below, because I am updating the data in the first run.

```
    [[0u8; 128],[3u8; 128],[2u8; 128]]
```

I am guessing that my use of Arc is wrong and that it is actually a clone of SharedData being passed around instead of a reference to SharedData, but I don't know how I can identify this.
How can I fix the code to make it work as I intended?

main.rs:

```
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::RwLock;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio_task_pool::Pool;

struct SharedData {
    data: Arc<RwLock<Vec<[u8; 128]>>>
}

impl SharedData {
    fn new(data: RwLock<Vec<[u8; 128]>>) -> Self {
        Self {
            data: Arc::new(data)
        }
    }

    fn update(&self, index: usize, update_data: [u8; 128]) {
        let read_guard_for_array = self.data.read().unwrap();
        let write_lock = RwLock::new((*read_guard_for_array)[index]);
        let mut write_guard_for_item = write_lock.write().unwrap();
        *write_guard_for_item = update_data;
    }
}

fn socket_to_async_tcplistener(s: socket2::Socket) -> std::io::Result<tokio::net::TcpListener> {
    std::net::TcpListener::from(s).try_into()
}

async fn process(mut stream: tokio::net::TcpStream, db_arc: Arc<SharedData>) {
    let read_guard = db_arc.data.read().unwrap();
    println!("In process() read: {:?}", *read_guard);
    db_arc.update(1, [3u8; 128]);
}

async fn serve(_: usize, tcplistener_arc: Arc<tokio::net::TcpListener>, db_arc: Arc<SharedData>) {
    let task_pool_capacity = 10;

    let task_pool = Pool::bounded(task_pool_capacity)
        .with_spawn_timeout(Duration::from_secs(300))
        .with_run_timeout(Duration::from_secs(300));
    
    loop {
        let (stream, _) = tcplistener_arc.as_ref().accept().await.unwrap();
        let db_arc_clone = db_arc.clone();

        task_pool.spawn(async move {
            process(stream, db_arc_clone).await;
        }).await.unwrap();
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let addr: std::net::SocketAddr = "0.0.0.0:50051".parse().unwrap();
    let soc2 = socket2::Socket::new(
        match addr {
            SocketAddr::V4(_) => socket2::Domain::IPV4,
            SocketAddr::V6(_) => socket2::Domain::IPV6,
        },
        socket2::Type::STREAM,
        Some(socket2::Protocol::TCP)
    ).unwrap();
    
    soc2.set_reuse_address(true).unwrap();
    soc2.set_reuse_port(true).unwrap();
    soc2.set_nonblocking(true).unwrap();
    soc2.bind(&addr.into()).unwrap();
    soc2.listen(8192).unwrap();

    let tcp_listener = Arc::new(socket_to_async_tcplistener(soc2).unwrap());

    let mut vec = vec![
        [0u8; 128],
        [1u8; 128],
        [2u8; 128],
    ];

    let share_db = Arc::new(SharedData::new(RwLock::new(vec)));
    let mut handlers = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..num_cpus::get() - 1 {
        let cloned_listener = Arc::clone(&tcp_listener);
        let db_arc = share_db.clone();

        let h = std::thread::spawn(move || {
            tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
                .enable_all()
                .build()
                .unwrap()
                .block_on(serve(i, cloned_listener, db_arc));
        });
        handlers.push(h);
    }

    for h in handlers {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "tokio-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
log = "0.4.20"
env_logger = "0.10.0"
tokio = { version = "1.34.0", features = ["full"] }
tokio-stream = { version = "0.1.14", features = ["net"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.193", features = ["derive"] }
serde_yaml = "0.9.27"
serde_derive = "1.0.193"
mio = {version="0.8.9", features=["net", "os-poll", "os-ext"]}
num_cpus = "1.16.0"
socket2 = { version="0.5.5", features = ["all"]}
array-macro = "2.1.8"
tokio-task-pool = "0.1.5"
argparse = "0.2.2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked at the entire code, but there are a few errors.

## `fn update()`

```rust
    fn update(&self, index: usize, update_data: [u8; 128]) {
        let read_guard_for_array = self.data.read().unwrap();
        let write_lock = RwLock::new((*read_guard_for_array)[index]);
        let mut write_guard_for_item = write_lock.write().unwrap();
        *write_guard_for_item = update_data;
    }
```

That's not how you use a `RwLock`:

- if you want to modify the data, instead of using `self.data.read()`, use `self.data.write()`;
- I'm not sure what you intend to do with this the second `RwLock`, but it is useless.

Rather, do something like

```rust
    fn update(&self, index: usize, update_data: [u8; 128]) {
        let write_guard_for_array = self.data.write().unwrap();
        write_guard_for_array[index] = update_data;
    }
```

## `fn process()`

```rust
async fn process(mut stream: tokio::net::TcpStream, db_arc: Arc<SharedData>) {
    let read_guard = db_arc.data.read().unwrap();
    println!("In process() read: {:?}", *read_guard);
    db_arc.update(1, [3u8; 128]);
}
```

Generally, you probably shouldn't access `db_arc.data` directly. But beyond that, once you fix function `update()`, this is going to deadlock:

1. You acquire `db_arc.data.read()`. By definition of a `RwLock`, this means that nobody can modify the contents of `db_arc.data` until the read lock is released.
2. The read lock is released only at the end of the scope.
3. Before the end of the scope, you call `update()`, which is going to attempt to acquire `data.write()`. But it cannot acquire it until the read lock is released.

You probably want something along the lines of:

```rust
async fn process(mut stream: tokio::net::TcpStream, db_arc: Arc<SharedData>) {
    {
      let read_guard = db_arc.data.read().unwrap();
      println!("In process() read: {:?}", *read_guard);
    } // End of scope, `read_guard` is released.
    db_arc.update(1, [3u8; 128]);
}
```

## tokio + threads

You're mixing threads and tokio. It's theoretically possible, but risky. Both choices are valid, but I suggest picking either one or the other. Typically, pick tokio if you have lots of I/O (e.g. network requests or disk access) or threads if you have lots of CPU usage.

Comment: I wouldn't say mixing tokio and threads is *risky* per se, but if you're not conscious of the foot guns you'll end up tanking your I/O performance by blocking during cooperative async. Great answer otherwise.

Comment: Well, I haven't tested, but I suspect that using tokio's Mutex/RwLock with threads will panic while using stdlib's Mutex/RwLock will fail to release the lock during `await` and possibly deadlock.

Comment: If you use tokio sync primitives you probably need to use a tokio runtime, since the components are picky that way; but you absolutely can use std sync in tokio, with the caveat that all blocking calls will block your runtime (which could absolutely deadlock, we may be talking past each other on this point)

Comment: Yoric-san and MeetTitan-san, Thank you for more detail information about deadlock and tokio / std libs.
If we use tokio, is it safer to assume that everything is safer with tokio? (I was not aware that Mutex/RwLock also has one for tokio. Maybe SockAddr and Arc also have them, I will check them out).

Answer (score 1):

```
fn update(&self, index: usize, update_data: [u8; 128]) {
    let read_guard_for_array = self.data.read().unwrap();
    let write_lock = RwLock::new((*read_guard_for_array)[index]);
```

This creates a copy of the data and wraps it in a useless `RwLock` (useless because that copy is always kept in a single thread).

```
    let mut write_guard_for_item = write_lock.write().unwrap();
    *write_guard_for_item = update_data;
}
```

This modifies the copy, which then gets immediately discarded at the end of the function.

Instead you need to lock the `RwLock` that you already have:

```
fn update(&self, index: usize, update_data: [u8; 128]) {
    let mut write_guard = self.data.write().unwrap();
    write_guard[index] = update_data;
}
```

Note that there is no way to get a write lock for only a specific item and read locks for the whole array: both read and write locks must relate to the same data. That means you also need to release the read lock before you can update:

```
async fn process(mut stream: tokio::net::TcpStream, db_arc: Arc<SharedData>) {
    let read_guard = db_arc.data.read().unwrap();
    println!("In process() read: {:?}", *read_guard);
    drop (read_guard);
    db_arc.update(1, [3u8; 128]);
}
```

Comment: I believe that @jmb and myself agree that either answer would do the trick :)